# Unable to eat in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have opened a [ticket](http://getsatisfaction.com/mojang/topics/i_cant_eat) about this at getsatisfaction, however, as no one else has reported it as a bug, I was wondering if anyone else here has seen this problem.

I can eat once within an instance of the game, then not again until I 'quit to title' and return. I have tested this with cooked ham and bread, and it appears to have started at 1.2.6

Could this be a corruption in one of my files, or is someone else able to replicate this bug?

**EDIT** I am playing Single Player Survival

Comment: single player or multi player?

Comment: @Raven Dreamer, thanks, amended question accordingly

Comment: With regards to whether anyone else has noticed this problem, I have not. I did however notice that earlier whenever I paused the game the resume button returned me to the title screen. I suppose this is what we get for being alpha testers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This turned out to be a knock on effect of the bug fix of the issue where it would perform a right click action (empty water buckets, user flint to light a fire, fire an arrow) when opening a door or crate. The upshot is that you now must walk away from a crate before eating (otherwise you just end up opening the crate and not eat)